# Not able to enter backtick properly only on one site

Tags: html, angular, keyboard, backticks

I am unable to enter the backtick character properly on a site I contribute to. It makes the next character I type as accented. In other sites such as this I have no problem. I can easily type backticks to make text appear as `code`. I have a qwerty en-US keyboard. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The site uses Angular 2. Is there some setting that I can change to make the backtick work properly?

Comment: can you share this website address so I can try?

Comment: @crash https://beta.gmantra.org/ Try in the username field itself.

Comment: weird indeed... I don't know I'm sorry. Interesting thing is that in the password field it works normally